# Error linking file while everything looks fine

Tags: php, html, require, require-once

I am having a problem in linking the file. I am sure that I have no problem from my side as I have checked everything from my side. Here is what I have uploaded(via FileZilla),
[image]

While on the [website](http://www.apptec.net/RemindMe/demo4.php) it displays that it can not find this file.

> Warning: require_once(classes/tc_calendar.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/content/34/8707934/html/RemindMe/demo4.php on line
>   52
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'classes/tc_calendar.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/34/8707934/html/RemindMe/demo4.php on line 52

Now I have tried my level best to find where the bug is and now I am out of ideas. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path seems to be wrong, I think you forgot a directory

```
require_once('calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

This file:
/home/content/34/8707934/html/RemindMe/demo4.php
On line 52 is looking for file located inside classes/ called tc_calendar.php

You have to change this line to the correct path:

```
require_once('calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');
```